# Telephone number probability

Tags: probability

Three strangers meet in a cafe, each with a mobile telephone number comprising of 11 digits. 
On exchanging telephone numbers they find that all three end with the same two digits in the same order, (lets say each ends xxxxx xxxx99)
What is the probability that this would happen based purely on the telephone number variables?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Note:  I don't imagine that phone numbers are assigned randomly, though you are probably meant to assume that the last two digits are chosen uniformly at random from $\{00,01,\cdots, 99\}$.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework assignments and which show no effort.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  Can you do it with two people instead of three?

Comment: Phone numbers are not assigned randomly in practice, or at least they used to not be assigned randomly in the US. For instance, in ABC - DEFG, the digit B would never be a 0 or a 1 (those were reserved for area codes), and the digit D being a 9 was a strong indication that the number was either commercial or (more likely) a "pay phone." Perhaps the last two digits really *are* uniformly random, but I wouldn't bet on it. I'm pretty sure that the digit A is still never a 0 or a 1, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume, that the phone numbers are from the set $\{0,1,...,99999999999\}$, then the probability of such situation can be caluculated that way:

1. First we take a look at the first phone number. How many numbers ends with the same two digits as this one?

   > $$ frac{100000000000}{100}=1000000000$$
2. We know, that the second phone is different than the first one. How many phones are different than the first one?

   > $$100000000000-1=99999999999$$
3. How many phones ending like the first one, but different from it there are?

   > $$1000000000-1=999999999$$
4. And the third phone - how many are different than the first and second?

   > $$100000000000-2=99999999998$$
5. How many ends like the first, but are different from the first and second, assuming, that the second one also ends like the first one?

   > $$1000000000-2=9999999998$$
6. Thus we could calculate the probability for such situation

   > $$P=\frac{999999999}{99999999999}\frac{999999998}{99999999998}$$

Comment: Thankyou Jaroslaw for helping with this.